# Would like to block key presses for x amount of time

Tags: python

I want to write a code to block keyboard input for **x** amount of time and stumbled across this code:

```
import keyboard
import time

for i in range(150):
    keyboard.block_key(i)
time.sleep(0.2)
```

It blocks input for `0.2` seconds.

But unfortunately this does not work and it blocks my keyboard inputs until I close the Python reader. Anyone can help?

Comment: What is the "Python reader"?

Comment: Looks like you're using a package external to the standard library. When that's the case, please mention it and link the package in your question so that we have a better understanding of the context.

Comment: Thank you all for the input! Sorry I am very very new to coding. I am using IDLE- is using the term “package reader” to refer to IDLE correct?

Comment: [IDLE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html) is a cross-platform IDE for python, written in python.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) package from PyPI.

You need to call [`unhook_all`](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboardunhook_all), or [`unhook(key)`](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboardunhookremove).

Comment: Thank you all for the input! Sorry I am very very new to coding. I? 

I will bear in mind to link the external package next time I’m asking a question, cheers!